# Setting optional parameters for Ruby on Rails' root on routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a static_pages controller in order to serve all my static page content. I want to be able to pass parameters to this static page content in order to open several modal boxes for login and message popups.

```
root 'static_pages#home'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in the view with Javascript if certain params exist.

For example, in home.html.erb

```
<% if params[:your_param] == true %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // fire modal
  </script>
<% end %>
```

And then just add your param to the query string:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/?your_param=true
```

No need to modify the routes file. The modals are view-related, so why not keep the logic in the view?

As far as your comment goes about a conditional redirect, sounds like a job for the controller. You have access to params in the controller as well, so you can redirect as needed depending on the params passed to the action.

Comment: And how can I call my controllers with the redirect_to to send that parameter? Or I would have to redirect manually?

Comment: You have access to params[:your_param]  in the controller as well, so you could do a conditional redirect based on the value/presence of specific params

Comment: It worked perfectly :) I actually made it nicer: I look for 'your_param' (In my case I call popup, I don't know if its the best name) and I look at its value. Depending on that value I load diff. content, but I load it remotely so it looks a lot more elegant. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it which *does* used `routes.rb` is this:

```
 # config/routes.rb
 get 'posts/:id(/:opt1(/:opt2(/:opt3)))' => 'posts#show'
```

Then debug the params in the view

```
 # app/views/posts/show.html.erb
 <%= params %>
```

If the URL is  `posts/1/A/B/C` This will show:

```
 {"controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"1"
  "opt1"=>"A", "opt2"=>"B", "opt3"=>"C"}
```

The parentheses in the route are optional and treated as params to the non-parenthesis part of the route.

Comment: That's also pretty good, wish I could accept that answer as well!